# Why isn't this operation giving me greater precision?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm estimating the value of Pi using the following formula:

[image]

Using the following C++ code:

```
double sub = 0;
int prec = 1000; //How many iterations to use in estimate.

for(int i = 1; i <= prec; i++){
    double frac = 1/((3+(2*(i-1))) * pow(3, i));
    sub += (i == 1) ? 1-frac : (i%2) ? -frac : frac;
}

double pi = sqrt(12)*sub;

cout << "Pi estimated with precision of " << prec << " iterations is " << pi << ".\n";
```

My problem is that even at 1000 (or 100000 for that matter) iterations, the highest precision I'm getting is `3.14159`. I've tried using `static_cast<double>()` on each of the numbers in the calculation but still get the same result. Am I doing something wrong here, or is this the max precision this method will yield? I'm new to C++, but not to programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is you don't print all the precisions. you need to call,

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << ...
```